# How to use Dask.Array.From_Zarr to open a zarr file on Dask?

Tags: python, numpy, dask, python-xarray, zarr

I'm having quite a problem when converting a zarr file to a dask array. This is what I get when I type  `arr = da.from_zarr('gros.zarr/time')` :
[image]

but when I try on one coordinates such as time it works:
[image]

Any Ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: do you know how it was written? can you open it with [`xarray`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_zarr.html), as in `xr.open_zarr('gros.zarr')`?

Comment: also I think zarr arrays need to be named. there should be a group for your array inside the directory, e.g. `gros.zarr/gros`. Can you just `ls` the directory to find the name of the array?

Comment: Yes , I can open it with xarray.

Comment: Oh great! Does that answer your question then?

Comment: But I want to open it as a DaskArray. Xarray reads it but then you need to convert it to a Dask dataframe and then a dask array, but unfortunately you loose all the metadata when doing so

Comment: Oh no not at all! da.data goes straight to a dask.Array if the array is chucked. In most cases, an xarray dataset or DataArray created from a zarr array is already a dask array, just wrapped in an xarray container. See https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/dask.html and also https://examples.dask.org/xarray.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read a zarr array in xarray, dask will be enabled by default, unless you specify `chunks=None`. You absolutely do not have to go through dask.dataframe - you can go straight from [`xarray.DataArray`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#dataarray) to [`dask.Array`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array-api.html). In fact, there's not even a copy required - all you need to do is access the [`.data`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.data.html) attribute underlying the DataArray.

Here's an example from a file I have laying around:

```py
In [3]: import xarray as xr
   ...: import os
   ...:
   ...: fp = os.path.join(
   ...:     ROOT_DIR,
   ...:     'ScenarioMIP/INM/INM-CM5-0/ssp370/r1i1p1f1/day/tasmax/v1.1.zarr'
   ...: )
   ...: 
   ...: ds = xr.open_zarr(fp)
   ...: ds
Out[3]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 720, lon: 1440, time: 31390)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -89.88 -89.62 -89.38 -89.12 ... 89.38 89.62 89.88
  * lon      (lon) float64 -179.9 -179.6 -179.4 -179.1 ... 179.4 179.6 179.9
  * time     (time) object 2015-01-01 12:00:00 ... 2100-12-31 12:00:00
Data variables:
    tasmax   (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(365, 360, 360), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes: (12/47)
    Conventions:                  CF-1.7 CMIP-6.2
    activity_id:                  ScenarioMIP AerChemMIP
    contact:                      climatesci@rhg.com
    creation_date:                2019-06-17T08:27:21Z
    data_specs_version:           01.00.29
    dc6_bias_correction_method:   Quantile Delta Method (QDM)
    ...                           ...
    sub_experiment_id:            none
    table_id:                     day
    tracking_id:                  hdl:21.14100/da7e759e-3979-42e4-b92f-02e7e2...
    variable_id:                  tasmax
    variant_label:                r1i1p1f1
    version_id:                   v20190618
```

You can think of xarray [`Dataset`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#dataset)s as fancy dictionaries holding DataArrays as objects. [`DataArray`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#dataarray)s themselves are just N-dimensional arrays with labeled indices. The data contained in a DataArray is provided by an array "backend", which is usually numpy or dask.Array. When you read in a zarr dataset, the result will be a dask.Array with a bit of extra xarray index & metadata handling on top. We can see that the values in this array are a dask array by inspecting the array preview at the top:

```py
In [4]: ds.tasmax
Out[4]:
<xarray.DataArray 'tasmax' (time: 31390, lat: 720, lon: 1440)>
dask.array<open_dataset-51b28ad08603ab401a85808d9fa3d6d7tasmax, shape=(31390, 720, 1440), dtype=float32, chunksize=(365, 360, 360), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -89.88 -89.62 -89.38 -89.12 ... 89.38 89.62 89.88
  * lon      (lon) float64 -179.9 -179.6 -179.4 -179.1 ... 179.4 179.6 179.9
  * time     (time) object 2015-01-01 12:00:00 ... 2100-12-31 12:00:00
Attributes:
    cell_measures:  area: areacella
    cell_methods:   area: mean time: maximum (interval: 1 day)
    comment:        maximum near-surface (usually, 2 meter) air temperature (...
    coordinates:    height
    history:        2019-06-17T08:27:21Z altered by CMOR: Treated scalar dime...
    long_name:      Daily Maximum Near-Surface Air Temperature
    original_name:  tasmax
    standard_name:  air_temperature
    units:          K
```

Xarray is a great library which allows you to use pandas-style indexing in an N-dimensional space. But if you want to work with the dask.array directly, you can simply access the [`.data`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.data.html) attribute on a dask-backed xarray DataArray:

```py
In [5]: ds.tasmax.data
Out[5]: dask.array<open_dataset-51b28ad08603ab401a85808d9fa3d6d7tasmax, shape=(31390, 720, 1440), dtype=float32, chunksize=(365, 360, 360), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
```

Comment: what if you have multiple data variables ? How would you extract the dask arrays ?

Comment: I think I've found it. You convert the dataSet to dataArray, then use the  [xarray.DataArray.chunk()](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.chunk.html) . Then recover the dask array with data method

Comment: Or you could just access each one’s data method separately! No need to concat unless you actually want the data concatenated.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments by @Michael Delgado, if `xarray` works, then that's probably the best option.

However, if for some reason you do want to open it with `dask.array`, then you can specify the component of interest using `component` kwarg:

```py
from dask.array import from_zarr

x = from_zarr("gros.zarr", component="time")
```

For some reproducible examples, see [this blog post](https://coiled.io/blog/creating-dask-array-from-zarr/).

Comment: Well , I found a solution. I opened the zarr with xarray then i converted it to a dask daraFrame then a Dask  array.I didn't lose any metadata too.

Comment: That's interesting, but sounds like a hack... so it might be worth exploring further to get a more robust solution.